# What is this stain on my brick?

Tags: brick

My house has a pinky brown brick on the front. When we moved in 9 years ago it had a bit of a green tinge to it, but not bad. Over the years it has gotten worse. We have tried powerwashing, having a house cleaner come and use a detergent on it, and bleach and nothing seems to remove it. I'm not sure what to try next.[image: picture of stained brick]

Here's what it should look like:
[image: Good Brick]

Comment: I really don't see the green.

Comment: I don't see the green either.  Some of the bricks look more grey than pink, but not really green.  Perhaps you could mark up the photo to point if there are particular spots (using Windows Paintbrush or any picture editor program)?

Comment: I still don't really see the stain.

Comment: Have you tried bleach? You can use an old toothbrush and any bleach to test a small area.

Comment: getterdun - I did try bleach, and it doesn't seem to have an effect.

Comment: For those of you that don't see the stain, that makes me feel better. :) It's glaring to me... but hopefully not as noticeable to somebody else.